# using find() in cakephp3

Tags: sql, cakephp, datasource, cakephp-3.0

How can I use find() to execute queries such as :

```
select * from table1 
where status =1 and (title like '%keyword%' OR content like '%keyword%');
```

in cakephp 3

Comment: There is the *awesome* manual, ever tried to simply use it for these *very* basics? See http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html &  http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html Also doing the blog tutorial *really* helps to getting started with the framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using functions as the parameters to `orWhere()` and `andWhere()`, you can compose conditions together with the expression objects:

```
$query = $table1->find()
        ->where(['status' => 1])
        ->andWhere(function ($exp) {
            return $exp->or_([
                'title LIKE' => '%keyword%',
                'content LIKE' => '%keyword%'
            ]);
 });
```

or you can simply use below code

```
$query = $table1->find()
    ->where([
        'status' => 1,
        'OR' => [['title LIKE' => '%keyword%'], ['content LIKE' => '%keyword%']],
    ]);
```

For details please see [link](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#advanced-conditions)